# Determining the order stat of an array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Sorry if the formatting is bad. The question and code are below. I came across this array algorithm problem and I am stuck on how to solve it. I was thinking of sorting the array and then iterating through it but I am stuck. Any pointers/solutions for this one?

> Write a program that, given an array of N distinct integers and number K, will determine the K order statistic of the array. K is an integer between 1 and N: 1 ≤ k ≤ n. The K order statistic is the K smallest entry in the array. So the N order statistic is simply the maximum value in the set. The median, in other words, the middle element, is the n/2 order statistic.
>
> Input:
>   The first line of input will contain the order of statistic kk to determine. The second line of input will contain a space-separated array of integers to use for the statistical set. For example:
>
> 3
>
> 5 2 9 7
>
> Output:
>   The integer that is determined to be the kk order statistic of the given array. For example:
>   7

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
// k = low
// n = high
// median = n/2
// QuickSelect
public class Main {

  int low;
  int high;
  int[] arr; 

  public static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high){
    int pivot = arr[high];
    pivotloc = low;

    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++){
      if(arr[i] < pivot){
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[pivotloc];
        arr[pivotloc] = temp;
        temp++;
      }
    }
    int temp = arr[high];
    arr[high] = arr[pivotloc];
    arr[pivotloc] = temp;

    return temp;
  }
  public static int kSmallest(int k, int low, int high int[] arr){
  int partition = partition(arr,low,high);
    if (partition == k){
      return arr[partition];
    }
    else if (partition < k) {
      return kSmallest(arr, partition + 1, k);
    }
    else {
      return kSmallest(arr, low, partition - 1, k);
    }
  }     

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    int[] array = new int[5, 2, 9, 7];
    int[] arraycopy = new int[5, 2, 9, 7];
    int kPosition = 3
    int length = array.lnegth;

    if (kPosition > length){
      System.out.println("Index out of bound");
    }else {
      System.out.println("Smallest element in array:" + kSmallest(arraycopy, 0, length - 1, kPosition-1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) with average running time of O(n) and you don't need to sort.

Comment: Thanks, how would you code it in this specific situation? I am looking at QuickSelect and I am not sure they want us to code the entire selection algorithm

Comment: It is not that difficult to implement, follow that wiki or any standard book, first understand what is QuickSelect and then you will be able to implement easily.